# (key:value) key as in dictionary format and value as in list format

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to get something like this:

```
{'eve': [19, 50, 'fail'], 'walle': [79, 65, 'pass'], 'sandy': [28, 49, 'fail'],'bob': [15, 60, 'pass']}
```

What I tried to achieve this is:

```
def try_dic_from_list(names, ages, scores):
    for s in scores:
        p= "pass" if s >=60 else "fail"
    mydict={key:value for key,value in list(zip(names,zip(ages,scores,str(p))))}
    print(mydict)
print(try_dic_from_list(["walle", "sandy", "eve", "bob"], [79, 28, 19, 15],
                                      [65, 49, 50, 60]))
```

This outputs this:

```
{'walle': (79, 65, 'p'), 'sandy': (28, 49, 'a'), 'eve': (19, 50, 's'), 'bob': (15, 60, 's')}
```

Any suggestions to get the square brackets instead of parenthesis and also how can I achieve the string in the list that pass or fail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are zipping the last `pass` or `fail` string with other values, so it is seen as a sequence of characters to zip.

Zip *first*, then include a `pass` or `fail`:

```
def try_dic_from_list(names, ages, scores):
    return {name: [age, score, 'pass' if score >= 60 else 'fail']
            for name, age, score in zip(names, ages, scores)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> def try_dic_from_list(names, ages, scores):
...     return {name: [age, score, 'pass' if score >= 60 else 'fail']
...             for name, age, score in zip(names, ages, scores)}
...
>>> try_dic_from_list(["walle", "sandy", "eve", "bob"], [79, 28, 19, 15], [65, 49, 50, 60])
{'bob': [15, 60, 'pass'], 'sandy': [28, 49, 'fail'], 'eve': [19, 50, 'fail'], 'walle': [79, 65, 'pass']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and pointing out the mistake:)

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Sorry, you can only mark *one* answer as accepted; pick the one you feel helped you the most! (Not picking one at all is also allowed).

Comment: Actually both the answers are similar. So, I just wanted to pick both.

Comment: I'm really sorry, that's not an option that SO offers. Your options sare to pick one or none. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Saying what you need to do on one line, this gives:

```
def try_dic_from_list(names, ages, scores):
    return {name: [age, score, "pass" if score >= 60 else "fail"] for name, age, score in zip(names, ages, scores)}

print(try_dic_from_list(["walle", "sandy", "eve", "bob"], [79, 28, 19, 15],
                                      [65, 49, 50, 60]))

# {'bob': [15, 60, 'pass'], 'walle': [79, 65, 'pass'], 'eve': [19, 50, 'fail'], 'sandy': [28, 49, 'fail']}
```

Comment: So neat, awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

The indentation inside the function seems to be the biggest problem, specifically the fact that it loops over the scores and only sets a final value for `p` at the end. You need some way to store the passes and fails for each score, not just the last one.

The `mydict` line is also really muddled and I struggle to make much out of it (so will another developer who reads this and yourself when you read this three months from now).

I've rewritten it so it works and looks a bit more sane:

```
def try_dic_from_list(names, ages, scores):
    pees = []
    for s in scores:
        p= "pass" if s >=60 else "fail"
        pees.append(p)

    values = [list(x) for x in zip(ages, scores, pees)]
    final_zip = zip(names, values)

    dict = {key:value for key,value in final_zip}
    return dict
```

If you're concerned about performance, you can certainly reduce the number of comprehensions made, but this is at least more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: I tried for one liner so it might look like that. I want to practice one liners. Thank you. I will keep in mind next time.:)

Comment: Ok yeah, the answer by @DainDwarf is a perfect one liner then. Glad I could help though :)